# Where is defined flutter.ndkVersion in build.gradle?

Tags: flutter, gradle

I am able to build the apk but with a warning of a wrong ndk version.
I have gradle-7.5-all.
In my android/app/build.gradle i have the following code:

```
android {
    namespace "com.example.pull_to_refresh_rive_flutter"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

I found the file local.properties with the following:

```
flutter.sdk=C:\\app\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

Notice that nor compileSdkVersion nor ndkVersion are specified.

I did a search with 'ndkVersion' on the whole directory android and found nothing (only ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion in build.gradle).

Where are defined flutter.compileSdkVersion and flutter.ndkVersion ?

Thank you guys.

Comment: From flutter root directory: `./packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`. You can find the constants in `FlutterExtension` class.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I write an 'answer your question'

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to 3nws, I found where it is defined.
It's no more in the project but in the flutter distribution.
<flutter_dir>\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy

We have:

```
class FlutterExtension {
    /** Sets the compileSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int compileSdkVersion = 33

    /** Sets the minSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int minSdkVersion = 19

    /** Sets the targetSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int targetSdkVersion = 33

    /**
     * Sets the ndkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects.
     * Chosen as default version of the AGP version below as found in
     * https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#default-ndk-per-agp
     */
    static String ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Same issue with sourceCompatibility, it's set to VERSION_1_8 in generateed build.gradle, however i need VERSION_17. I updated flutter.goovy with VERSION_17 but it doesn't change generated gradle.